# A question related to bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Let $f\in C^{BV}([0,1])$ (i.e. continuous and has bounded variation). Let the intervals $I$ and $T$ satisfy the following:  $I\subset T\subset [0,1]$ and for sufficient small $\delta>0$, $\frac{|I|}{|T|}\leq \delta.$

Question: Is there an $\epsilon=\epsilon(\delta)>0$ such that
$$\frac{\underset{I}{Var}f}{\underset{T}{Var}f}\leq \epsilon.$$

Comment: Isn't that $Var_I(f) \leq Var_T f$?

Answer (score 0):

As posed, the question has a trivial answer (as hinted by John in a comment): let $\epsilon=1$, then the inequality holds by the monotonicity of $\operatorname{Var}$.

A better question would be: is it true that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that $$|I|\le \delta |T| \implies \operatorname*{Var}_I f\le \epsilon \operatorname*{Var}_T f \tag{?}$$

The answer is negative; [the Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is a counterexample. This function is of the form $f(x)=\mu([0,x])$ where $\mu$ is a singular measure. Since $ \operatorname*{Var}_I f = \mu(I)$ , the validity of (?) would imply that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, which is not the case.